# Excel: Insert new line every x rows with content according to a pattern

Tags: excel

I have a long list in excel with two columns. Every 26 rows, I want to insert two new lines, pushing the remaining rows further down. So basically I have

```
26   ABC
27   DEF
28   GHI
```

and want to make it

```
26   ABC
27
28
29   DEF
30   GHI
```

Additionally, if it's possible, I'd like to put text into those new lines according to a simple pattern:

```
1_sometext
1_someothertext

2_sometext
2_someothertext
```

So the ones starting with "1_" would go into rows 27 and 28, the ones starting with "2_" would go into rows 55 and 56, and the number keeps incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible. You just need to write VBA macro for this which should look like this one

```
Sub someSubForLazyGuy()

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Set currentSheet = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim spaceCounter As Long

    rowCounter = 27
    spaceCounter = 1
    With currentSheet
        Do While .Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value <> ""
            .Cells(rowCounter, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(rowCounter, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = spaceCounter & "_sometext"
            .Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Value = spaceCounter & "_someothertext"
            spaceCounter = spaceCounter + 1
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 27 + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

And it works just simple. You loop rows and every 27 row you insert 2 new rows. Then you fill your sometext and someother text on this two lines, shift row counter by 27 rows and plus 1 for your new row and so on until there are data in column...