# Read Column A, insert rows based on pattern

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Column A that looks like this:

```
A
B
A
B
B
B
A
B
A
B
```

Some points:

1. All A's must have at least one B. All A's have a B, all B's have an A. (it's an accounting system - it requires this).
2. Any A can have as many B's as needed.
3. After each A.B[n] combo, we need a C.
4. The C must be an inserted row. Sorting and Filtering is not allowed (A, B, and C are variables that aren't replaced with alphabetical characters like seen here).
5. The code should not insert a C above the first A.

Expected output:

```
A
B
C
A
B
B
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

I've already looked at this: [Excel: Insert new line every x rows with content according to a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328165/excel-insert-new-line-every-x-rows-with-content-according-to-a-pattern)
but the pattern is based on a known 27-line insertion. This has no guaranteed pattern in my problem.

Comment: What if an `A` has no `B` ?

Comment: I like the exercise.  I just wish that you showed your code.

Comment: @Displayname All A's have a B by the file design. Great question, added to logic points above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a forward thinker, I used multiple  `Do` loops.

```
Sub InsertCs()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const A As String = "A", B As String = "B", C As String = "C"
    Dim r As Long, r2 As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Do
            r = r + 1
            If .Cells(r, "A").Value = A And .Cells(r, "A").Offset(1).Value = B Then
                r2 = r + 1
                Do
                    r2 = r2 + 1
                Loop Until Cells(r2, "A").Value = "" Or Cells(r2, "A").Value = A Or Cells(r2, "A").Value = C

                If Not Cells(r2).Value = C Then
                    .Rows(r2).Insert xlDown
                    .Cells(r2, "A").Value = C
                End If
                 r = r2
            End If
        Loop Until Cells(r, "A").Value = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: TinMan is my winner for two reasons: Application.ScreenUpdating=FALSE runs faster, and he declared "Sheet1" when @user10781941 didn't. TinMan, my only personal preference is on organization of declared variables A B and C, user10781941's is more user friendly!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim A, B, C
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long

    A = "A"
    B = "B"
    C = "C"

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    n = 1
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
    vR(1) = vDB(1, 1)
    For i = 2 To r

        If vDB(i - 1, 1) = B And vDB(i, 1) = A Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = C
        End If
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = vDB(i, 1)
    Next i
    If vR(n) = B Then
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = C
    End If
    Range("c1").CurrentRegion.Clear
    Range("c1").Resize(n, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

If you want multi column then

```
Sub test2()
    Dim vDB, vR(), vS()
    Dim A, B, C
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    A = "A"
    B = "B"
    C = "C"

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    col = UBound(vDB, 2)

    n = 1
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To col, 1 To n)
    For j = 1 To col
        vR(j, n) = vDB(1, j)
    Next j

    For i = 2 To r

        If vDB(i - 1, 1) = B And vDB(i, 1) = A Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To col, 1 To n)
            vR(1, n) = C
        End If
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To col, 1 To n)
        For j = 1 To col
            vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    If vR(1, n) = B Then
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To col, 1 To n)
        vR(1, n) = C
    End If
    Set Ws = Sheets.Add 'Sheets("Result")
    With Ws
        .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(n, col) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great concept but it fails with multiple columns.

Comment: @TinMan, What mean multiple columns?

Comment: @TinMan, I don't think that  OP wants to multi column. But  I added answer.

Comment: `r As Long` should be `j as Long` and `.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Clear` is no longer needed,  Nice work!! +1

Comment: test() is written to test Column C. Even after adjusting to test Column A, it will delete any additional columns (Column B or more) as TinMan said. I then used test2(), found that J wasn't declared as a variable. Fixed and it works as intended. I would avoid use in the wild though because I need it to work unsupported, and there is a lot more code here. Good organization though!

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>1. All A's must have at least one B.</sub>

Since all A's must have at least one B, your logic seems to boil down to: *If current cell is not B and cell directly above is B then insert row and paste C.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant

    a = "A"
    b = "B"
    c = "C"

    With Worksheets("sheet3")

        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 To 3 Step -1
            Select Case .Cells(i - 1, "A").Value2
                Case b
                    If .Cells(i, "A").Value2 <> b Then
                        .Rows(i).Insert
                        .Cells(i, "A") = c
                    End If
            End Select
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Lol..that was too easy.

Comment: You get an upvote because it works out-of-the-box, it's simple, and I can change my variables super fast (top declarations). Only problem was the declaration of "sheet3", which is not the default on a new workbook. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MultipleSearch()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim lrow As Long

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & lrow)

    Cells(lrow + 1, 1) = "C"

     For i = rng.Cells.Count To 2 Step -1
        If rng.Item(i) = "A" Then
            Rows(i).Insert
            Cells(i, 1) = "C"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP's question was how to insert a "C" when ever there is a "A"-"B" combination. Your code inserts a row above ever "A". But if you run a simulation you will see that it does not insert a "C" when there are multiple "B's" after an "A".

Comment: I tried this and it fails as GMALC says - it just looks for AB, and won't tolerate ABBBBBB before inserting C. Also, it inserts a C above the first A. Also, i wasn't a declared variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code. It will loop from the last cell in column A and if there is a variable varA then varB, it will insert a row and add varC. Assign your variables as needed.

```
Dim varA As Variant, varB As Variant, varC As Variant

Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, lRow As Long

varA = "A"
varB = "B"
varC = "C"

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = varB And Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1).Value = varA Then
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i, 1).Offset(1).Value = varC
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I tried this but it over-simplifies. It adds a C above the first A, which is not intended and doesn't happen with the other codes. Otherwise, love the organization and simplicity.

Comment: @C.A.R. I'm sorry but using your supplied data and running this code, it does NOT add a "C" above the first "A". There is absolutely no way this code could insert a "C" above an "A"; if it finds a "B" and an "A" in the cell above it, will it only insert a "C" below the "B" cell. you might have gotten it confused with the previous answer.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. It does, however, fail the ABBBBB test. It's producing ABCBBBBB instead of ABBBBBBC

Comment: @C.A.R. your right, I passed over the "each A.B[n] combo" in your question. I will modify it to correct that oversight, for anyone else that may review your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Find and some do loops is a way to do it...

```
Sub InsertC()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Data As Range: Set Data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = Data.Find("A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    Dim NextCell As Range, ACell As Range: Set ACell = FirstCell

    If Not ACell Is Nothing Then
        Do
            Set NextCell = ACell
            Do While NextCell.Offset(1, 0) = "B"
                Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)
            Loop
            If Not ACell = NextCell Then
                NextCell.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                NextCell.Offset(1, 0) = "C"
            End If
            Set ACell = Data.Find("A", After:=NextCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        Loop While ACell.Address <> FirstCell.Address
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```